# Excel: if date + days = specific weekday then

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, weekday

**Current table**:
[image]

I want to write a if condition to sum 2 column date and see if it's equal to a specific day of the week.

**E.g.**
=If(weekday(A2)+B2 = 1, "Sunday", "Not Sunday")
In words: If A2 + B2 = Sunday, then...

In this example, since A2 is Thursday and adding B2 which is 3 days, the result should be Sunday. It should then return "Sunday".

The solution doesn't work because weekday(A2)+B2 is not equals to 1 (1 in weekday function refers to Sunday). I can't specific weekday(A2)+B2 = 1 because A2 and B2 are subjected to changes (B can be 1 to 100).

*How should I change my if-condition*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WEEKDAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) function has two parameters (second is optional). You can add the second parameter equal 2 to get 7 as Sunday, and change formula to:

`=If(weekday(A2,2)+B2 = 7, "Sunday", "Not Sunday")`

Another possible solution is to add day offset inside `WEEKDAY`

`=If(weekday(A2+B2) = 1, "Sunday", "Not Sunday")`

Third option would be using `MOD(...,7)`.